# ¿Cómo cambio colores de TextViews y botones en Android Sutdio?

Tags: android

Mi problema es que trato de cambiar el color de fondo de un textview y un botón, lo hago desde la vista de design y por lo que veo los colores si se aplican en el archivo xml, pero por alguna razón al cargarlos ya a un dispositivo virtual o a un celular no me aparecen ninguno de los cambios. Aparecen como si solo hubiera arrastrado y colocado el textview y el botón y ya.

[image: Así se supone que se debe de ver]

[image: Pero al cargarla a un dispositivo se ve así.]

[image: Este es el archivo xml de la actividad.]

Comment: agerga el codigo de tu vista  xml para poderte ayudar

Comment: Muchas gracias wrocano, ya añadí la imagen del código xml de la actividad.

Comment: prueba cambiando el color con android:background = "@android:color/holo_green_light", tambien intenta añadir el texto como texto y no como imagen para poder verlo mas rapido

Comment: Realiza el cambio que te recomienda Julian ya que `tools:"---"` solo te permitira ver los cambios que deseas
durante la vista previa del diseño y nunca se va a ver reflejado cuando este en ejecución. [Documentación](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes)

Comment: Wow, bueno siempre se aprende algo nuevo. Funcionó perfectamente, gracias a ambos. La verdad es que acabo de instalar android studio en otra computadora, ya había trabajado con android dtudio antes y nunca me habían pasado estas cosas con el IDE. No sé si sea la versión que ésta es mas nueva pero he tenido que hacerle varios cambios a los proyectos porque se crean por default con errores y eso antes no me pasaba en la versión que trabajé anteriormente.

Comment: @LuisPaulín si puedes poner la respuesta como correcta se agradece :) asi queda como que esta solucionada

Comment: Si @JulianYbarra, no encontraba donde se aceptaba jeje Pero ya está muchas gracias. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prueba cambiando el color con

```
<TextView
...
android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
.../>
<Button
...
...
android:background="{tu color}"
... />
```

como dice A.Palacio

> `tools:"---"` solo te permitira ver los cambios que deseas durante la
>   vista previa del diseño y nunca se va a ver reflejado cuando este en
>   ejecución. [Documentación](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes)